# Evaluate live javascript edits in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How do I tell the Chrome developer tools that I'm done live-editing a section of javascript, and want the result to be "evaluated"?
Editing the javascript on the fly is simple, I simply put the cursor somewhere in a script in the Scripts tab and start typing, but how do I finish the editing process?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5506786/125938) that "changes you apply to the code are expressed only at the time when execution passes through them", <strike>but even if I try editing a function when it's being called (i.e., when having a hit breakpoint inside it), I can't get my changes to be acknowledged.</strike> Edit: this whole, "execution passes through it" stuff seems false or out of date at best.

Editing javascript on the fly in the developer tools is demoed by Paul Irish in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI) around 3:30, but I can't figure out how he goes from editing code, to having it actually be used by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> or "right-click > Save".
Make sure you haven't enabled pretty-print, as you can't live-edit code, then.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

1.- Navigate to the Source tab and open the javascript file

2.- Edit the file, right-click it and a menu will appear: click **Save** and save it locally.

In order to view the diff or revert your changes, right-click and select the option **Local Modifications**... from the menu. You will see your changes diff with respect to the original file if you expand the timestamp shown.

More detailed info here: http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

- Go to sources, choose the file you want.
- Click the pause button to pause debugging .
- Modify the script adding a console.log or whatever you want, wherever you want
- Save the file (cmd-s or ctrl-2)
- Click the pause/resume button to resume execution
- the modified code will be executed