# Chrome Developer Tools: missing Script tab

Tags: debugging, gwt, google-chrome

Web browser - chrome Version 21.0.1180.82 and Version 23.0.1244.0 canary
OS - mac osx 10.8

What it should look like:

[image]

In my view the "Script" tab within the tab navigator is replace by an icon saying "Sources".  This is causing me problems as I cannot debug my GWT app in super dev mode. (I have selected the option "Enable Source Maps")

I have also disabled all extensions.

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks,

Comment: It's been renamed and some icons have changed and other things have moved around, but it should work the same. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce,  I was trying to debug my gwt app using chrome's developer tools, and could not load any of my java files.  I thought it was because I did not have the "Script" tab.  I followed the documents here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode

After adding to my app.xml file  <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true"/> everything works fine.

Thanks again

Comment: `compiler.useSourceMaps` is automatically added by Super Dev Mode, so probably you were _using_ it (you have to launch the `CodeServer` and then click the _Dev Mode On_ bookmarklet, and possibly hit F5 afterwards, depending on when you opened the developer tools)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The scripts tab has been re-named to `Sources` shown as below:

[image: Example of Chrome 23]

To see a list of all scripts/js files you will need to use the fly-out (shown as 2)

This is the case in chrome 23 however it may change again in the future.

Comment: Ctrl+F will search within the currently viewed script but I am not sure you can search across all scripts

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F to search all scripts