# How to edit js file under chrome developer tools application tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a Javascript file under application tab(not Sources) and I want to edit this Javascript file but chrome doesn't have an option like edit. Is there any other way to edit this JS file?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067532/editing-in-the-chrome-debugger Check this answer

Comment: @MandeepJain There is no js file under sources tab.