# Jboss 7 dont see javascript changes

Tags: javascript, jboss

When jboss 7 is running and i change javascript file i need restart server to browser see the changes.

Some way the force jboss view the changes without restart it?

Answer (score 0):

How do you deploy your application file? Is it a completely built and packaged .ear file? If it is, there is no possibility other than a full rebuild. If it is not, then you can explode deploy with Ant.

Another approach, you can live edit the .js files from the browser:
[Editing in the Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067532/editing-in-the-chrome-debugger)

and that way you can completely avoid jboss.

Comment: Thanks Ognjen Mišić to try help me. I discover the problem. This problem occurs when my workspace be corrupted. In this case i change my IDE workspace and everything works fine. This is a bug from IDE eclipse. Occasionally this happens, not just with me but with my team friends.