# How to save changes to modifications of external site JS Code

Tags: javascript, web, microsoft-edge

I have recently been trying to mess around with JS code of different websites to explore the programming language further. I have been able to successfully modify the scripts of the websites but I cannot find a way to save the changes and they do not take effect. I am using the newer Microsoft Edge (Version 92.0.878.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit)).

[image: snapshot of error]

It shows that "changes to this file were not saved to the system", how do I go about this?

(please note: this website is external and I have tried downloading the HTML and modifying it but then the site does not function)

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue?

Comment: @YuZhou the breakpoint method did not work for me and i am not skilled enough to set up a javascript workspace

Comment: The breakpoint method won't remove the info "changes to this file were not saved to the system", but it will show the result of the changes. For the Workspace method, you just need to follow the steps in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/workspaces/#step-1-set-up). If you have encountered any issue when you set up workspace, you can describe the problem you have and I'll try my best to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior if you don't add the files to workspace. If you want to save the changes to file system, you need to use **Filesystem-> Workspace**.

You can refer to [Edit files with Workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/workspaces/) about the detailed steps of using Workspace. After [Step 1: Set up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/workspaces/#step-1-set-up), you can directly go to [Step 4: Save a JavaScript change to disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/workspaces/#step-4-save-a-javascript-change-to-disk).

Besides, there's another workaround to test the changed js code without saving to file system. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067532/editing-in-the-chrome-debugger/13019242#13019242) about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows file system is preventing chrome from saving file with special chars. Chrome is using filenames to match files on your local version with ones on the webpage.

Because of windows replacing special chars ("?") With escaped ones ("%3"), chrome is unable to match them and shows that error.

I don't know the perfect solution for that, but one of the workarounds would be to remove cache canceling string with question mark. Very nasty bug of local overrides.